# Why isn't my subclass inheriting a method from the superclass?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass, superclass

In a blackjack game I have the following piece of code:

```
class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
        
        
    def hand_score(self):
        ...
    
    
class Dealer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        Hand.__init__(self)
```

Where `hand_score()` should calculate the score in `self.hand` and return it's value. However when I assign `dealer = Dealer()`, deal the cards and call `dealer.hand_score()` it gives me the error `AttributeError: 'Dealer' object has no attribute 'hand_score'`.
The `self.hand` value is inherited and works as expected when I call `dealer.hand`.

Comment: It's _not_ a superclass. `Dealer(object)` is not `Dealer(Hand)`.

Comment: `class Dealer(object):` -> `class Dealer(Hand):`, though I would argue that inheritance is not the correct relationship between a dealer and a hand of cards.  A dealer isn't a hand of cards, a dealer _has a_ hand of cards.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `class Dealer(object):`, what do you expect that to mean? In particular, what do you expect the `(object)` part to mean? If this is not simply a typo, then please review a tutorial on classes.

Comment: Never mind that a dealer is not a kind of hand, so inheritance is probably not appropriate in the first place.

Comment: @chepner My guess is that the code is not making proper distinctions between hands and the players who hold them - as is common enough in projects like this. Proper *modeling* is hard to teach.

Comment: Actually I'm starting the classes on "declaring classes". This blackjack game is like a "homework" and I'm not supposed to do it "correctly", probably the idea is to point out our mistakes and solve them in class. Anyway thanks for the feedback, it helped me a lot, I'll start looking into class tutorials right now to try to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually inheriting from `Hand`; you are just inappropriately using `Hand.__init__` to initialize an unrelated instance.

`Hand` has to be listed as a base class in the class definition.

```
class Dealer(Hand):
    def __init__(self):
        Hand.__init__(self)  # preferably, super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class Dealer(object):
```

should be:

```
class Dealer(Hand):
```

Otherwise your class will only sub-class the 'object' class.